# How can I separate one row from a data set but repeat in each line some of the variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where each row contains information that needs to be separated and printed in different rows, but I need to keep the name of the company on each newly printed row:

example dataset
These are the headers:

```
company | marketing_budget | marketing_remaining | finance_budget | finance_remaining | sales_budget | sales_remaining
```

These are 2 rows of data:

```
Law Office | 450,000 | 150,000 | 300,000 | 100,000 | 200,000 | 50,000
Restaurant | 30,000  | 7,000   | null    | null    | 25,000  | 10,000
```

I need to separate one line into as many as I need. Some companies might have a marketing budget but don't have a finance budget or any other possible combination...
So the output should look like this (also I need to add the department, which is not included as a column, it is only the title of the column where the info is taken)

```
Company    | Department | Budget  | Amount Remaining
Law Office | Marketing  | 450,000 | 150,000
Law Office | Finace     | 300,000 | 100,000
Law Office | Sales      | 200,00  | 50,000
Restaurant | Marketing  | 30,000  | 7,000
Restaurant | Sales      | 25,000  | 10,000
```

Comment: Use `pandas`. That would definitely be the easiest approach.

Comment: How is your dataset stored? What are you using to manipulate it? Is what you have the literal text, or a representation of what your tables look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a text file that looks like:

```
Law Office | 450,000 | 150,000 | 300,000 | 100,000 | 200,000 | 50,000
Restaurant | 30,000  | 7,000   | null    | null    | 25,000  | 10,000
```

We can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' \| ', engine='python')

# Reverse the column names on '_'.
df.columns = ['_'.join(reversed(x.split('_'))) for x in df.columns]

# Use pd.wide_to_long
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['budget', 'remaining'], i='company', j='department', sep='_', suffix=r'\w+').sort_index()
df = df.reset_index().dropna()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      company department   budget remaining
0  Law Office    finance  300,000   100,000
1  Law Office  marketing  450,000   150,000
2  Law Office      sales  200,000    50,000
4  Restaurant  marketing   30,000     7,000
5  Restaurant      sales   25,000    10,000
```

---

Testing, and how I'd make the values numeric for future calculations:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

d='''company | marketing_budget | marketing_remaining | finance_budget | finance_remaining | sales_budget | sales_remaining
Law Office | 450,000 | 150,000 | 300,000 | 100,000 | 200,000 | 50,000
Restaurant | 30,000 | 7,000 | null | null | 25,000 | 10,000'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep=' \| ', engine='python')
df = df.fillna('').applymap(lambda x: x.replace(',', ''))
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='ignore')

df.columns = ['_'.join(reversed(x.split('_'))) for x in df.columns]

df = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['budget', 'remaining'], i='company', j='department', sep='_', suffix=r'\w+').sort_index()
df = df.reset_index().dropna()
print(df)

....

      company department    budget  remaining
0  Law Office    finance  300000.0   100000.0
1  Law Office  marketing  450000.0   150000.0
2  Law Office      sales  200000.0    50000.0
4  Restaurant  marketing   30000.0     7000.0
5  Restaurant      sales   25000.0    10000.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Python package `pandas` to build the table. And also using list comprehension, and `list.split()` method to process the data

```
import pandas as pd

d='''company | marketing_budget | marketing_remaining | finance_budget | finance_remaining | sales_budget | sales_remaining
Law Office | 450,000 | 150,000 | 300,000 | 100,000 | 200,000 | 50,000
Restaurant | 30,000 | 7,000 | null | null | 25,000 | 10,000'''

data = [e.strip().split('|') for e in d.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame([[e.strip() for e in l] for l in data[1:]], columns=[e.strip() for e in data[0]])
print(df)
```

Output

```
      company marketing_budget marketing_remaining finance_budget finance_remaining sales_budget sales_remaining
0  Law Office          450,000             150,000        300,000           100,000      200,000          50,000
1  Restaurant           30,000               7,000           null              null       25,000          10,000
```

After this, use `df.melt()` and `df.pivot()` methods to get the final results!

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='company')
df[['department','value_type']] = df.variable.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.pivot(index=['company', 'department'], columns='value_type', values='value').sort_index().reset_index()
df = df[df['budget']!='null']
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      company department   budget remaining
0  Law Office    finance  300,000   100,000
1  Law Office  marketing  450,000   150,000
2  Law Office      sales  200,000    50,000
3  Restaurant  marketing   30,000     7,000
4  Restaurant      sales   25,000    10,000
```

Thanks @BeRT2me, good learning for me!

Comment: If you change to: `data = [e.strip().split(' | ') for e in d.split('\n')]` then the next part is made much simpler: `df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])`

Comment: oh yea, that's a good one! I'm trying to do `e.strip()` for each element in data...

Comment: I think what you have for the first section is good, (Assuming that's how OP's data is formatted). With that, you can use my method to make the secondary table.

Comment: @BeRT2me yes i'm trying to do `.split('|')` and handle the whitespace later, but it looks very cumbersome! `[[e.strip() for e in l] for l in [data[i].strip().split('|') for i in range(1,n)]]`

Comment: There's also a far easier way to read in the data that I've shown~

Comment: thanks @BeRT2me, I found a way using `df.melt()` and `df.pivot()` to get the final table!